# Older version of excel does not do array formulas properly?

Tags: excel

```
=SUM(IF((A:A="a")*(B:B="b1")+(B:B="b2"),1,0)*(C:C))
```

Why does this formula not work?

It works if I restrict the number of rows

```
=SUM(IF((A1:A10="a")*(B1:B10="b1")+(B1:B10="b2"),1,0)*(C1:C10))
```

Thanks in advance.

Actually I just tried it on my home computer, both formulas work. But the first one did not work when I was at work on my office computer. Office computer has an older version of excel.

office is 2007 vs home is 2013

Comment: also try this formula: `=SUMPRODUCT(((A:A="a")*(B:B="b1")+(B:B="b2"))*(C:C))`. It doen's requre array entry.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference an entire column in an array formula due to performance reasons as described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/166342).

> **The "entire column" rule**
>
> Although you can create very large arrays in
>   Excel, you cannot create an array that uses a whole column or multiple
>   columns of cells. Because recalculating an array formula that uses a
>   whole column of cells is time consuming, Excel does not allow you to
>   create this kind of array in a formula.

Obviously you can bypass this by simply referencing a large part of the column (or the whole column - `A1:A65535` - for Excel 2003) or by using dynamic ranges.